# Is there a way to make a thumbnail clickable in dropzone?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

What i want to do is that when I add a file or is loaded from an autoscan (load all attachments made from an user), I would like to have an event that can give me the information about the thumbnail preview.

Example :  in my dropzone gallery there are 4 images ; I want to click on every image and obtain the information (filename,size,etc.etc).
Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a ***solution for this problem***, even if it's not what I have to do for my work.
If you take any example of dropzone, and use **Inspector** from Mozilla/Chrome or IE, upload a file and then with your inspector click on your uploaded file.

As you can see, there are two `id's` : `dz-details`  and `dz-size` 
**Jquery** comes in our help and we can access every single bit of the DOM, right?

So I would suggest in your javascript / Angular module to write like this :

```
        $('#dz-details').on('click', function()
         {
              console.log("filename :",$('#dz-filename').value());
         });

          $('#dz-size').on('click', function()
         {
              console.log("size :",$('#dz-size').value());
         });
```

That's it, just normal and pure **Jquery.on('click') function**